# How to explain this low-pass phenomenon?

Tags: analog, integrated-circuit, transfer-function, cadence

I'm trying to understand how a coupling capacitor works, and build the following circuit.[image]

The transfer function (obtained from an AC simulation) from the voltage source (V2) to the gate voltage of the NMOS transistor (net 016) behaves like a low-pass filter somehow (cut-off frequency is about 13.8MHz), and I don't know how to explain this.

I guess it may be caused by the input capacitance of the transistor. Assume the input capacitance is C2, then the transfer function should be
$$
\frac{\frac{C1}{C1+C2}}{1+s\cdot \frac{C1C2R}{C1+C2}}
$$

However, this doesn't make sense. Because the gain is 1 at low frequency, forcing C2 = 0.

[image]

Comment: Gain is perhaps within a pixel of 1.0 but need not be exact. Why not measure C2 with another method, like plotting V2[i]?

Comment: @TimWilliams Do you imply that C2 is much smaller than C1, and is the reason causing this low-pass phenomenon? It makes pretty much sense as the time constant is now dominated by C2R.....

Comment: It's not really a coupling capacitor, if there's no load resistance on the far side; the gate has ~no leakage so the highpass response is N/A.

Answer (score 1):

The gate input resistance is very high. At low frequencies \$X_{C1}\$ dominates \$R\$ so the gate-input circuit is a capacitive voltage divider formed with \$C_1\$ and \$C_2\$. So the high pass filter that a coupling capacitor usually provides is not present.

Comment: Is the gate input resistance and the input capacitance in parallel in this model (because these two are in series in Sansen's book, which makes it hard to understand)?